# Contradiction on a probability computation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have a set of positive random variables $\boldsymbol X=\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\}$, where $X_1, X_2,\ldots$, are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.). The CDF $F(x)$ and PDF $f(x)$ for $X_i$ are known in advance.

Define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

How to compute $P(S_{n-1} \le T,\; T < S_n \le s)$? ($T$ is a constant, $s$ is a variable.)

---

Here is what I thought:

$\eqalign{P(S_{n-1} \le T,\; T < S_n \le s) \cr 
= P(S_{n-1}\leq T,\; T-S_{n-1}<X_n\leq s-S_{n-1}) \cr
=P(S_{n-1}\leq T)P(T-S_{n-1}<X_n\leq s-S_{n-1})}$

(because $S_{n-1}$ and $X_n$ are independent.)

Let $t$ denote $S_{n-1}$, and $r$ denote $X_n$, we have

$$P(t\leq T)P(T-t<r\leq s-t)=\int_0^T dt\;  f_{n-1}(t) \int_T^s dr\; f(r-t)$$
where $f_{n-1}$ is the $n$-fold convolution of $f(x)$.

But the result of the above formula is a function of $s$ and $t$, while from the original question, the result should be a function of $s$. Can some one give me a hand on this?

Comment: Whether or not the final formula is correct, it is not a function of $t$. $t$ is the variable of integration.

Comment: @zoli why? the two integrals a not nested, so $\int_T^s dr\; f(r-t)$ is a function of $s$ and $t$.

Comment: using the independence of $S_{n-1}$ and $X_n$, 
$$\mathbb{P}\big( S_{n-1}\leq T, T - S_{n-1} < X_n \leq s - S_{n-1}   \big) =\mathbb{E}\Bigg\{ \mathbb{E}\Big[ 1_{( S_{n-1}\leq T )}\cdot 1_{ ( T - S_{n-1} < X_n \leq s - S_{n-1} )}  \vert S_{n-1}\Big]  \Bigg\} $$
$$ = \mathbb{E}\Big[ 1_{( S_{n-1}\leq T )} \cdot \big( F(s- S_{n-1}) - F(T - S_{n-1})  \big) \Big] = \int_{-\infty}^T \big( F(s- \ell) - F(T - \ell)  \big) dG(\ell)
$$where $G$ is the c.d.f. of $S_{n-1}$, you can compute this in terms of $F$ and $n$. (assume $s > T$)

Comment: @Chival I believe this is correct! Comparing with my answer, I should put $dt$ to the end of the formula. But why won't you say $\int_{-\infty}^TdG(\ell) \big( F(s- \ell) - F(T - \ell)  \big) $? This is where I feel puzzled. Because intuitively, it should be the product of two integrals rather than a double integral.

Comment: Please check that the step "$P(S_{n-1}\leq T,\; T-S_{n-1}<X_n\leq s-S_{n-1})=P(S_{n-1}\leq T)P(T-S_{n-1}<X_n\leq s-S_{n-1})$ (because $S_{n-1}$ and $X_n$ are independent.)" is wrong.

Comment: @Did Yes, now I understand it is incorrect. Chival provides a good way to solve this (using conditional expectation). Do you have your own way to towards this?

Comment: @Bloodmoon,  this is just notational preference. As I know, French mathematicians like to put dt or dx next to the integral sign, for example, $$\int_{\text{domain}} \mu(dx)  \text{some function} . $$

Comment: @Chival I mean, if you compare your answer and my answer, you can find the difference is just the location of $dt$, but this makes the answers totally different (yours is the correct one). So I think it's not just notational preference. Your answer to this question is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

**First**

You cannot say that "let $S_{n-1}=t$" unless you are to manipulate a conditional probability:

$$P(S_{n-1}<T)\not =P(t<T).$$

Rather

$$P(S_{n-1}<T)=E[P(S_{n-1}<T\mid S_{n-1})]$$

and

$$P(S_{n-1}<T\mid S_{n-1}=t)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if }t \ge T\\
1, & \text{ if }t< T 
\end{cases}=\chi_{\{t<T\}} .$$

And then
$$E[P(S_{n-1}<T\mid S_{n-1})]=E[\chi_{\{S_{n-1}<T\}}]=\int_{\{t<T\}}f_{S_{n-1}}(t) \ dt.$$

Unfortunately, however, this trick does not bring us closer to the solution to the original problem if we don't know the density of $S_{n-1}.$

**Second**

Consider the same for $$P(T-S_{n-1}<X_n\leq s-S_{n-1})$$ with $S_{n-1}=t, X_n=r$.

Comment: I actually mean let $t$ denote $S_{n-1}$, and I have corrected this by editing the question. Have you finished your answer?

Comment: Even then, a random variable cannot be the variable of integration. I cannot say more.

Comment: I got your point, thanks!